# Dashes showing as empty boxes in man pages in a Cygwin/X terminal

Tags: cygwin

Pretty much what the title says, works fine in a plain (non-X) Cygwin window.  It's probably a charset thing. In case it's related:

```
$ echo $LANG
C.UTF-8
```

I ungzipped the man page for less and the start looks like so:

```
.TH LESS 1 "Version 429: 11 Apr 2009"
.SH NAME
less \- opposite of more
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mintty terminal or do 'alias man="LANG=C man"'.

Comment: urxvt-X also works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by setting my terminal (PuTTY) to UTF-8. PuTTY defaults to Latin-1 but Cygwin 1.7 now defaults to UTF-8. Check your terminal configuration.

http://turbulentsky.com/cygwin-funny-characters-man-pages-putty.html